# right align pandas data frame in flask

Tags: python, html, css, pandas, flask

I am creating a API in flask. I want to display the pandas dataframe right opposite the upload button. I can google through various ways of justifying the column headers/text, but not the frame itself. The flask code used is:

```
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/upload', endpoint='upload_file1')

def upload_file1():
    df_table=data.head().to_html()   
    return render_template('upload.html', df_table=df_table)
```

html code is:

```
<html>
<head>       
<title>CR prediction tool</title> 

</head> 

    <body bgcolor="#E6E6FA">


      <form action = "http://localhost:5000/uploader" method = "POST" 
         enctype = "multipart/form-data" >
         <input type = "file" name = "file"  />
         <input type = "submit" />
         {% block content %}
         <style  align= "float:right">
         </style>   
         {{df_table | safe}}
         {% endblock %}
```

Comment: This can probably be done with css, can you post your upload.html template?

Comment: @MarkBeilfuss Added the template.

Comment: Looks like you didn't include the whole template. I don't see the closing tags for form or body.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to align html elements like this. Here is a simple way. Wrap both elements in their own div and use css to set the divs to `display: inline-block` and then give a fixed or percentage `width`. Let me know if this helps. For a working example check this jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/35fy20Ls/4/

```
<style>
    .inline-block {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 40%;
    }
</style>
<div class="inline-block">
    <form action = "http://localhost:5000/uploader" method = "POST" enctype = "multipart/form-data" >
        <input type = "file" name = "file"  />
        <input type = "submit" />
    </form>
</div>
<div class="inline-block">
    {% block content %}
    {{df_table | safe}}
    {% endblock %} 
</div>
```